# Write to texture in geometry shader and sample in fragment shader

Tags: vulkan

Is it possible to write to a texture in the geometry shader and sample this texture in the fragment shader? If so, how would the descriptors setup be done? How can an image be VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_IMAGE in the geometry shader while VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER in the fragment shader?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the reason you want to do this?

Comment: It's just a toy example with different approaches to do outlines to get familiar with vulkan and specifically descriptors. This case consists of doing an outline effect by generating a normals texture in the geometry shader and compare, per fragment, each normal and its adjacent fragments normals to get an avearge delta angle to know if that fragment should be outlined. 
I know it isn't efficient but it think it could be interesting to learn and doing something different from already existing vulkan examples.

Out of curiosity, what approach would you follow to do this GS exercise? :)

Comment: Honestly, I'd advertise against using geometry shaders... Compute shaders are mandatory in all Vulkan implementations, and they offer superior alternatives both in terms of performance and workflow semantics. I strongly believe they were put in Vulkan (with the Transform Feedback extension) to help developers port they application from GL to Vulkan. I mean, generating primitives on-the-fly cannot be good for performance. That aside, if you're looking for a smart way to draw outlines, Ben Golus wrote a very good article about this, entitled "The Quest for Very Wide Outlines".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to write to a texture in the geometry shader and sample this texture in the fragment shader?

Not as a sampled image.

You can write to a `coherent`-qualified storage image and read from it as a `coherent`-qualified storage image... so long as you stick to the visibility and availability rules.

A GS invocation writes one or more primitives. Those primitives generate fragments. The fragment shaders for those fragments can only read data written by the GS invocation that wrote their primitives (and even then, only the execute of those GS invocations up to the point where they call `EmitPrimitive` for their own primitive). Even GS invocations that theoretically should have happened earlier in submission order cannot be accessed.

Comment: can't I generate a normals texture with 'imageStore' in the GS without calling EmitVertex? and read from this texture in the fragment shader for current fragment and its adjacents to get how much normals change to detect edges?
I know there are better ways to do outlines but just wanted to practice something different.